# How can I get the Decimals in the following function in PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have the following doubt, I have this function to calculate dates between 2 dates, however these dates have hours, I have been working on the function to get the decimals however I still dont get the decimals,  I have tried ( Number.Round), (Decimal.From)

Please function below :

```
= (InitialDate as datetime, FinalDate as datetime ) as number => 
let
DaysBetweenDates = Duration.Days(FinalDate-InitialDate),
DaysList = List.DateTimes(List.Min({InitialDate,FinalDate}),Number.Abs(Decimal.From(DaysBetweenDates))+1.00, Duration.From(Decimal.From(2.00))),
WeekDaysList = List.Select(DaysList, each (Date.DayOfWeek(_, Day.Monday) < 5) ),
WorkingDays = (if DaysBetweenDates < 0.00 then -1.00 else 1.00) * List.Count(WeekDaysList)
in
WorkingDays
```

Comment: Take a look at `Duration.TotalDays` as a possible replacement for `Duration.Days` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-totaldays

Comment: You show nothing to indicate what you want for a result. What do you mean by "***get the decimals***"? Without knowing what you expect for output given a particular input, it is difficult to advise.  And the functions you are using do not have decimals as an output. You need to provide much more detail to explain.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for your comment,  the output that I need is when it i have   2 dates and different times i need the output of number days  in that period and time example: 1/11/21 7:00 am  to  1/12/21 5:00 am = out put 0.80 days

Comment: What logic are you using to get a result of the difference between those two datetimes of 0.80 days?  I calculate 22 hours difference and don't understand how you compute 0.80 days for a result.  It's not 22/24.

Comment: Once you hit `analysisservices` (ie: visuals, DAX, anything after import) , there is not a `duration` datatype, so you can't represent durations larger than 24 hours, withotu converting it to X seconds or X ms. Power Query is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your comment that your `0.80` days is incorrect (and should be `0.92` days), and that you are really looking for days and fractions of a day, you can use simply:

```
(InitialDate as datetime, FinalDate as datetime ) as number => 

let
    WorkingDays = Number.From(FinalDate) - Number.From(InitialDate)
in
    WorkingDays
```

*and you could also use `Number.Round` if you want to round the result*

eg:

```
Number.Round(Number.From(FinalDate) - Number.From(InitialDate),3)
```

If that is not what you want, you will need to be more specific.